# Strategy for graph paper background with major and minor grids?

Tags: html, css, svg, background

I would like to create a simple 100px by 100px image in Inkscape that has a major line every 100px and a minor line every 10px.

This way I can verify the size of my viewport when I use this as a repeating background as follows.

What is a good strategy for doing this?

I am thinking a color of #888888 for the major grid lines and something lighter for the minor grid lines such as #cccccc for the minor grid lines.

I would put a rectangle around the the 100px by 100px image creating the major grid lines ...

and then I would draw in each of the minor grid lines 10 in the x direction and 10 in the y direction.

Would this strategy work.

I'm worried the outer rectangle might look distorted and not uniform b.c. it is on the edge of the image.

Answer (score 1):

As I see it, you have two strategies:

1. **Position your major axes exactly at the borders of your image.**

   You will end up with half of the lines being cut off by the edges of the image.  But the other half of the edges should be visibly restored once they are in a repeating tile pattern.

   The disadvantage of this approach is that you can't do a clean 1px graph line.  Due to anti-aliasing, you will end up with a 2px line with half opacity.
2. **Position your major axes at the top row, and left column of the image.**

   Assuming you desire a 1px graph line. Draw your major horizontal graph line at the top pixel of your image (ie `y="0.5"`), and your major vertical graph line at the left-most pixel (ie `x="0.5"`).

To make sure you get clean 1px minor grid lines, make sure they also are positioned at half-pixel coordinates (ie. `10.5`, `20.5`, `30.5` etc), so that they sit exactly coinciding with the image pixels.